# toDataURL("image/png") to Facebook Upload

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, png

I'm creating a little paint app, and I want to give my painters the option of publishing their work on facebook. I'm using Raphael JS to create the image. Then I'm using the HTML5 Canvas method `toDataURL("image/png")` to create a javascript variable that holds the .png data of the image.

Now that I have this data, I can't figure out how to let people submit it to facebook! I tried using the `FB.ui()` function but it seems to only let me share an established link. If I try to share the stored data, Facebook replies my url is too long. How can I have that data upload to facebook instead of linking?

Is this impossible? I've looked everywhere, and I have not found a suitable answer. I know facebook is horribly documented!

THANKS!

Comment: My gut reaction is that it is very likely you'll have to send the image data to your own server, which will host the image and provide a valid HTTP URL back to your app to pass to the `FB.ui` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photo connection of the user object in the graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) has a `source` property.  This is where you will place the data content (multipart/form-data) of your photo.

Once you upload the photo data to the user account, it is placed in an album specially for your application.  You will get the id of the new photo from the `FB.api('me/photos','post',params,callbackFn);` call.

Using that photo id, you can get it's url and use it however you want.  You can even use it to post to the user's wall for everyone to see.

Comment: Thanks DMCS, I'll take a look at this and see if it it works. I knew there had to be a way.

Comment: I have a "(#324) Requires upload file" error. Does anyone now how to fix it ?